# Макрос-функция в С++

Tags: c++

```
#define MAX(x, y, r) {int rtemp=(((x)>(y)) ? x : y);\
                      r=rtemp; }
```

Функция должна сравнивать параметры **x** и **y** и присваивать **r** значение большего. Как можно её реализовать так, чтобы всё не ломалось при передаче следующих параметров:

```
int R = 14;
int a = 5;
int b = 6;

MAX(a,b,R++);
```

Выводит такую ошибку:

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment|
```

Comment: Никак. Да и зачем? Она и должна "ломаться" при такой передаче. `MAX(a,b,R++)` - это бессмыслица. Как можно что-то "присвоить" в `R++`?

Comment: @AnT Да, но дело в том, что решить такое как-то возможно. Может стоит реализовать функцию по-другому?

Comment: я бы сказал что этот макрос сломается от параметров `MAX(a++,b++,R)` хотя формально будет работать.

Comment: @Jaycobe: Сначала надо решить, что ваше макро должно делать. "Присвоить в `R++`" - это бессмысленное требование. Пока вы не сформулируете осмысленно, что именно ваше макро должно делать, нет смысла ничего реализовывать. А "решить" действительно возможно - вообще выкиньте из вашего макро все содержимое - и все будет прекрасно компилироваться даже с вашим `R++`.

Comment: Макрос в С++ - тем более такой - бессмыслица; а уж передавать в макрос заведомо неработоспособные параметры... Ну как вы себе просто представляете присвоение не переменной `r`, а `r++`? Что и, главное, **почему** мешает использовать для этого функцию?

Comment: @Harry Суть задачи состоит в том, чтобы использовать именно макрос.

Comment: @AnT Необходимо присвоить переменной **R** значение, в данном случае, **b**.

Comment: @Jaycobe: Ну так и напишите `MAX(a,b,R)`? Откуда взялся `++` и что он тут делает? И что должно произойти с этим `++`? Когда делается `++`? До того, как переменной присвоилось новое значение? Или после того? Или вообще не делается? Какое значение должно получить `R` в этом случае: `6` или `7`?

Comment: @AnT '++' делается до того, как присваивается значение переменной. 'R' должно получить значение '6'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы понять ошибку стоит знать, что оператор постинкремента возвращает значение до увеличения значения аргумента. Это значение временное и не может быть использовано в качестве левой части выражения присваивания.

Если уж всё же так сильно хочется добавить `++` к `R`, можно использовать преинкремент `++R`. Это выражение увеличит значение `R` и вернёт ссылку на переменную. Смысла в этом немного, т.к. в эту переменную сразу же запишется результат макроса, но по крайней мере код будет компилироваться. В общем же случае, никакой инкремент для задачи присваивания максимума вовсе не нужен.

Вполне будет работать вариант `MAX(a, b, R);`

---

На основании уточнения в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/#comment1391188_861531) я делаю вывод, что речь должно идти всё же об постикременте аргументов, задающих входящие значения, а не результат.

И проверка проваливается фактически на вызове вида:

```
MAX(a, b++, R);
```

Где в `R` должно попасть значение **до** модификации. Исправленный вариант макроса может выглядеть так:

```
#define MAX(x, y, r) {int X = (x); int Y = (y); r = X > Y ? X : Y; }
```

Comment: Проблема и состоит в том, что программа перестаёт работать, если использовать '++'  в качестве постфикса.

Comment: @Jaycobe так не используйте. Зачем он нужен в данном случае?

Comment: я бы с радостью, но, значения, подставляемые под макрос выбираю не я. Макрос должен работать в максимально возможном количестве ситуаций, и поэтому компьютер перебирает все возможные варианты.

Comment: @Jaycobe это с какого-то теста что ли? Надо чтобы работало при передаче чего попало в качестве аргументов?

Comment: именно. уже черт знает сколько не могу это решить

Comment: @Jaycobe если `R` остаётся целочисленной переменной, `R++` никогда нельзя будет использовать в качестве левой части присваивания. Это фундаментальная суть языка. Если же использовать свой тип с перегруженным постфиксным оператором инкремента, то можно уже сделать почти что угодно. Вы бы лучше задание описали как оно есть в оригинале, вместо того, чтобы решать неразрешимую проблему с присваиванием.

Comment: _Реализуйте макрос MAX от трёх параметров, который присваивает целочисленной (int) переменной, переданной в качестве третьего аргумента, наибольшее из значений, переданных в первых двух аргументах. Требования к реализации: вам нужно реализовать только макрос MAX. Функцию main и какие-либо другие функции реализовывать не нужно. Попробуйте решить эту задачу исключительно средствами макросов._ Как видите, только начинаю изучать азы C++ а там сразу такое.

Comment: @Jaycobe звучит нормально. Но откуда появляется инкремент всё равно не ясно. Поймите, использование `R++` в данном контексте равносильно вызову `MAX(a, b, 14)`. А это, согласитесь, лишено смысла.

Comment: @Jaycobe Так в задании про `R++` ни слова. Откуда идея, что макрос должен с таким работать?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ТС [упоминал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%a1#comment1390835_861531), что варианты входных аргументов выбирает кто-то (что-то) извне. Допускаю, что тестирующий код сам по себе глючный. Ссылку на первоисточник бы глянуть для большей ясности.

Comment: @alexolut (https://prnt.sc/kcec7i) вот полное условие, надеюсь это что-то прояснит. Текст ошибки гласит _Postfix increment test failed_, из-за чего я, собственно, и сделал такой вывод

Comment: @Jaycobe обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> *Суть задачи состоит в том, чтобы использовать именно макрос*
>
> *Необходимо присвоить переменной R значение, в данном случае, b.*

```
#define max(a,b)    (((a)>(b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define maxr(a,b,r) r = (((a)>(b)) ? (a) : (b))

int R = 14;
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
R = max(a,b);
maxr(a,b,R);

R++;  // :)
```

Comment: Я, судя по всему, неправильно изъяснился, присвоить R значение b необходимо также в самом макросе.